# Parsing character array to words held in pointer array (C-programming)

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

I am trying to separate each word from a character array and put them into a pointer array, one word for each slot. Also, I am supposed to use isspace() to detect blanks. But if there is a better way, I am all ears. At the end of the code I want to print out the content of the parameter array.

Let's say the line is: "this is a sentence". What happens is that it prints out "sentence" (the last word in the line, and usually followed by some random character) 4 times (the number of words). Then I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Where am I going wrong?

```
int split_line(char line[120])
{
    char *param[21]; // Here I want to put one word for each slot
    char buffer[120]; // Word buffer
    int i; // For characters in line
    int j = 0; // For param words   
    int k = 0; // For buffer chars

    for(i = 0; i < 120; i++)    
    {
        if(line[i] == '\0')
            break;
        else if(!isspace(line[i]))   
        {    
            buffer[k] = line[i];
            k++;    
        }    
        else if(isspace(line[i]))
        {
            buffer[k+1] = '\0';
            param[j] = buffer; // Puts word into pointer array   
            j++;    
            k = 0;    
        }   
        else if(j == 21)    
        {
            param[j] = NULL;    
            break;    
        }    
    }    

    i = 0;
    while(param[i] != NULL)    
    {    
        printf("%s\n", param[i]);    
        i++;    
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: `param[j]=NULL;` is an overflow for `j==21`, you want either a larger array or stop earlier. (It did not trigger with your short test sentence.)

Comment: You are re-using the same `buffer` for each of your pointers.

Comment: This line: int split_line(char line[120]) should be int split_line(char* pLine)

Comment: This line: for(i = 0; i < 120; i++) is using a hardcoded value, which is almost always a bad idea.  Rather use this line: for(i = 0; i < strlen(pLine); i++)  see above comment for where pLine came from

Comment: this line: param[j] = buffer; // Puts word into pointer array has an incorrect comment, as a pointer to the buffer array is all that is being moved.  In every case, the same pointer is all that is being moved.  also, the buffer must be cleared before each saving/extracting sequence.  To actually save the extracted words, try param[j] = malloc( strlen(buffer) +1 ); strcpy( param[j], buffer );  memset( buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer) );

Comment: this line: char buffer[120]; // Word buffer should be: char buffer[120] = {0}; // Word buffer  otherwise, the buffer will contain trash

Comment: this line: buffer[k+1] = '\0'; places the null byte one too many bytes into the buffer array, because 'k' is either 0 (no bytes in array) or already incremented past the end of the characters, in the prior code block.  also, this line is not needed if the buffer is properly initialized at the begining and when the extracted word is saved.

Comment: this line: char *param[21]; // Here I want to put one word for each slot   Actually you want to point to each saved word, as each 'slot' is only big enough for a pointer to char.  I also strongly suggest that the array be initialized by using this line: char *param[21] = {0};

Comment: Since all those calls to malloc are now being performed, the end of the code also needs to call free() for each entry in the param[] array.  (note, if properly initialized to 0, free can be called for each entry without worry about if the entry actually contains a pointer as calling free() with a null pointer is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many little problems in this code :

- `param[j] = buffer; k = 0;` : you rewrite at the beginning of buffer erasing previous words
- `if(!isspace(line[i])) ... else if(isspace(line[i])) ... else ...` : `isspace(line[i])` is either true of false, and you always use the 2 first choices and never the third.
- `if (line[i] == '\0')` : you forget to terminate current word by a '\0'
- if there are multiple white spaces, you currently (try to) add empty words in param

Here is a working version :

```
int split_line(char line[120])

{

    char *param[21]; // Here I want to put one word for each slot
    char buffer[120]; // Word buffer
    int i; // For characters in line
    int j = 0; // For param words
    int k = 0; // For buffer chars
    int inspace = 0;

    param[j] = buffer;

    for(i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
        if(line[i] == '\0') {
            param[j++][k] = '\0';
            param[j] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        else if(!isspace(line[i])) {
            inspace = 0;
            param[j][k++] = line[i];
        }
        else if (! inspace) {
            inspace = 1;
            param[j++][k] = '\0';
            param[j] = &(param[j-1][k+1]);
            k = 0;
            if(j == 21) {
                param[j] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    i = 0;

    while(param[i] != NULL)

    {

        printf("%s\n", param[i]);

        i++;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I only fixed the errors. I leave for you as an exercise the following improvements :

- the split_line routine should not print itself but rather return an array of words - beware you cannot return an automatic array, but it would be another question
- you should not have magic constants in you code (`120`), you should at least have a `#define` and use symbolic constants, or better accept a line of any size - here again it is not simple because you will have to malloc and free at appropriate places, and again would be a different question

Anyway good luck in learning that good old C :-)

Answer (score 1):

This line does not seems right to me

```
param[j] = buffer;
```

because you keep assigning the same value `buffer` to different `param[j]` s .

I would suggest you copy all the `char` s from `line[120]` to `buffer[120]`, then point `param[j]` to location of `buffer + Next_Word_Postition`.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand exactly why I should do "param[j] = buffer + i;" ? That line just puts the word into the pointer array.

Comment: you want to put different words into `param[j]`, right?  `param[j] = buffer;` keep assign `param[0]`, `param[1]`, ... the same value `buffer` which is `buffer + 0`;

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `strtok` in `string.h`. It sounds like this is what you are looking for, as it will separate words/tokens based on the delimiter you choose. To separate by spaces, simply use:

```
dest = strtok(src, " ");
```

Where `src` is the source string and `dest` is the destination for the first token on the source string. Looping through until `dest == NULL` will give you all of the separated words, and all you have to do is change `dest` each time based on your pointer array. It is also nice to note that passing `NULL` for the `src` argument will continue parsing from where `strtok` left off, so after an initial `strtok` outside of your loop, just use `src = NULL` inside. I hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I did look into strtok, and I guess it will work, but I think am supposed to use isspace().

Comment: Well `isspace()` recognize all white space characters : at least `" \t\r\n"`